# Нужно преобразовать случайное двоичное дерево в сбалансированное двоичное дерево удалением минимального количества вершин

Tags: python, бинарное-дерево

**Дерево называется двоичным**, если у каждой его вершины может быть максимум два потомка (левый и правый). Также у вершины может быть только один потомок или не быть потомков.

**Дерево называется сбалансированным**, если для каждой вершины высота левого и правого поддерева данной вершины отличаются не более, чем на 1. Например, если у вершины только один потомок, то этот потомок должен быть листом, так как другой потомок отсутствует и считается, что его высота равна 0.

Дано двоичное дерево, необходимо удалить минимальное число его вершин так, чтобы дерево стало сбалансированным. Оно задано списком смежности (**g**), если у вершины **v** левый или правый потомок отсутствует, то на этом месте стоит **-1**

Я целый день не могу найти ошибку в своем решении:

```py
def height(v, g, h):
    h[v] = 1
    for u in g[v]:
        height(u, g, h)
        h[v] = max(h[v], h[u] + 1)


def find_deleted_vertexes(v, cnt, g, h, ans):  # cnt - how many vertexes down v you shouldn't delete
    if cnt <= 0:
        ans.append(v + 1)
    # new cnt for leaves
    new_cnt = min([cnt - 1] + [(h[u] + 1 if u != -1 else 1) for u in g[v]])
    for u in g[v]:
        find_deleted_vertexes(u, new_cnt, g, h, ans)


def solve():
    n, g = entry()
    h = [0 for i in range(n)]
    height(0, g, h)
    ans = []
    find_deleted_vertexes(0, int(1e9), g, h, ans)
    print(len(ans))
```

Comment: Нужно вернуть список удаленных вершин (количество)